# ASP.NET MVC - Order By Date

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, html-table, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort table (columns: ID, Name, SermonDate, SermonTitle, BibleReading, VideoLink, BulletinLink) by date (SermonDate) so the data with the newest date comes on top and display it in my MVC application.

After some researching, I've tried putting the below with reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22095694/order-by-date-asp-net-mvc-5) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433088/asp-net-mvc-model-orderby-date-has-no-effect) but nothing worked for me - probably because I misunderstood and put wrong code though.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
     return View(await _context.Sermon.OrderBy(sermon => 
     DateTime.Now).Take(5).ToListAsync());
}
```

My current controller (SermonsController.cs):

```
public SermonsController(BKPCContext context)
    {
        _context = context;    
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Sermon.OrderBy(sermon => DateTime.Now).Take(5).ToListAsync());
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var sermon = await _context.Sermon
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        if (sermon == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(sermon);
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Name,SermonDate,SermonTitle,BibleReading,VideoLink,BulletinLink")] Sermon sermon)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(sermon);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(sermon);
    }
```

And the html table in /Sermons/Index.cshtml as below:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SermonDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SermonTitle)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BibleReading)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VideoLink)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BulletinLink)
        </th>
        <th>

        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SermonDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SermonTitle)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BibleReading)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VideoLink)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BulletinLink)
        </td>
        <td id="aspButton">
            <a role="button" id="btn-primary" class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a>
            <a role="button" id="btn-danger" class="btn btn-danger" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Sermon{
     public int ID {get;set;}
     public DateTime DateAdded {get; set}
} 

mySermonList.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateAdded);
```

Comment: I already had a Sermon class so I only added `mySermonList.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateAdded);` to my controller like this: `return View(await _context.Sermon.OrderByDescending(x => x.SermonDate).ToListAsync());` and it worked like charm. Thanks!

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue
sermon => DateTime.Now

you are sorting by DateTime.Now?
if sermon has date added field 
sermon => dateadded for example

Comment: I currently have only 3 rows of data (3 different dates) but the table shows them in descending order (newest date at bottom, oldest date on top). I want to reverse it and want the newest date to come up to the top.

Comment: How does your Sermon Object look like? I think Hope Mystery is right, you're trying to order by DateTime.Now, not the actual date property (?) of the Sermon Object